# Grep: could not find file

Tags: unix, grep, rm

In Unix environment, I need to write report to x_out file and also at the end of the process, the file needs to be removed. But, it always throws the following error.

```
grep: can't open /XYZ/123/Tmp/x_out

rm: /XYZ/123/Tmp/x_out non-existent
```

But, I can find the file x_out at the corresponding location. I'm able to open and view the contents too. I have found that sometime the file name changes with some '~' like characters appended to it. Is there a way to resolve this?

Edit: I'm not having any '~' appended to it. But, I have a doubt may be some unreadable chatacters like that have been appended.

Edit:I have added the actual error here

Edit: the command I used
grep "Report_values" ${REPORTOUT}|cut -d "|" -f 6

rm ${REPORTOUT}

Comment: Are you sure "the corresponding location" is what you think it is? (For example: have you tried inserting the `pwd` command right above the problematic command, so as to confirm that the present working directory is nested two down from the directory containing `x_out`?)

Comment: Add more details. Post your whole script.

Comment: if tilde is appended to a file, then it would be a backup file. Just remove tilde symbol. Now it would be displayed and you could do grep on that.

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash doesn't say `x_out is not existent`. Please copy the exact output and give the contents of your script...

Comment: @beroe updated the script. This is what I get.

Comment: You still are not showing us the command that your run to get the error. I tried zsh, csh, sh and bash and they all say `No such file or directory` if the file is not found. None say `can't open`. I can get a `cannot open` error if I don't have permissions to view the file in question. I am sure it will end up being something that makes you slap your forehead when you figure it out, but you are not giving us enough info.

Comment: @beroe Updated. Pl check. But, the problem is the file is not in the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are *two* possibilities I can see off the top of my head. There are undoubtedly more but the top of my head isn't a very big space :-)

The first is that the file *doesn't* exist despite your assertions.

The second is that it *does* exist but you're looking for it in the wrong place (for example, you've changed into a different directory).

If you place a line similar to:

```
( pwd ; cd ../.. ; pwd ; ls )
```

in your script before the `grep/rm`, it should tell you if either of those two possibilities is correct.

It will give your current directory, the directory you're looking in for the file and the files in that directory.

Comment: oh.. let me check that @paxdiablo

Comment: Thansk for teh eduts, @Yohanes, I smut be undre the affluence of incahol :-)

Comment: wlel, no porb, i'm srue aou yre.. =)

Comment: @paxdiablo yes.. Resolved. Problem with the path. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just check if you have non-printable/graphic character in the filename ... use -Q or -q flag of ls to see it... check below how it looks....

flag description from ls man page

```
   -q, --hide-control-chars
          print ? instead of non graphic characters

   --show-control-chars
          show non graphic characters as-is (default unless program is `ls' and output is a terminal)

   -Q, --quote-name
          enclose entry names in double quotes

   --quoting-style=WORD
          use quoting style WORD for entry names: literal, locale, shell, shell-always, c, escape
```

Demo Session

```
$ ls
demo.txt       test.dat
$ ls -1
demo.txt
test.dat
$ cat demo.txt
cat: demo.txt: No such file or directory
$ rm demo.txt
rm: cannot remove `demo.txt': No such file or directory
$ ls -Q
"demo.txt     "  "test.dat"
$ ls -1Q
"demo.txt     "
"test.dat"
$ rm "demo.txt     "
$
```

Comment: The problem is with the improper location. But, I have problem deleting some other file, which shows the non-existent error. Do this because of this reason of this non-printable characters.